# PostGIS functions: mixed CRS as arguments

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql

Does PostGIS support different CRS (coordinate reference system) as arguments in functions?

I tried this example:

```
SELECT ST_Intersects(
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(7.96491, 63.39051), 4326) ,
ST_MakeEnvelope(108233, 6983413, 259214, 7102542, 25833)
)
```

It should return `TRUE`, but it returns `FALSE`. But I do net get a error message either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostGIS tries to intersect the coordinates regardless of CRS. Obviously, your Point does not intersect with this Envelope.

You need to reproject one of the geometries to match the others CRS:

```
SELECT ST_Intersects(
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(7.96491, 63.39051), 4326) ,
ST_Transform(ST_MakeEnvelope(108233, 6983413, 259214, 7102542, 25833), 4326)
)
```

Comment: Note that the envelope is defined in EPSG:25833 yet, so there's not the need to set its SRID.

Comment: True... I missed that